# PyQT becomes unresponsive and sometimes crashing when adding 'too much' UI elements

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwidgets

[Unresponsive GUI image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWphS.png)

As shown by the image, the `UI` becomes unresponsive at initialization. Sometimes it works, but when I move the window around or resize it, it becomes **unresponsive** again. I do not think this can be solved by threading since I do not trigger any task when **clicking around** I only programmed the start button to do something but that is another story since I am not clicking it. Also I tried to remove the signal and slot of button but yielded nothing.

I initially thought that the `for loop` where I iterate through my file system to decide the look of grid layout is the culprit, since this may be the most computing intensive piece of code during initialization:

```
   

 for filename in os.listdir(self.MODEL_PATH):
        f = os.path.join(self.MODEL_PATH, filename)
        print(f)
        # checking if it is a file
        if os.path.isfile(f) and filename.endswith('.joblib'):
            dict ={
            "object": None,
            "checkbox": None,
            "label": None
            }
            clf_name = filename.replace('.joblib', '')
            self.classifiers[clf_name] = dict
            # dictionary
            self.classifiers[clf_name]['object'] = load(f)

            self.classifiers[clf_name]['checkbox'] = QCheckBox(str(clf_name))
            self.classifiers[clf_name]['checkbox'].setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
            self.classifiers[clf_name]['checkbox'].setStyleSheet("padding-left: 10px; border: 1px solid black;")
            self.classifierLayout.addWidget(self.classifiers[clf_name]['checkbox'], counter, 0, 1, 1)

            self.classifiers[clf_name]['label'] = QLabel('-')
            self.classifiers[clf_name]['label'].setStyleSheet("padding-left: 10px; border: 1px solid black;")
            # self.classifiers[clf_name]['label'].setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
            self.classifierLayout.addWidget(self.classifiers[clf_name]['label'], counter, 1, 1, 1)
```

**Workaround 1**
Turns out I was not entirely wrong, the line that caused the unresponsiveness is this line within the for loop:

```
self.classifierLayout.addWidget(self.classifiers[clf_name]['checkbox'], counter, 0, 1, 1)
```

By commenting that line, which prevents adding checkboxes to my layout, the `UI` works well.

**Workaround 2**
Further debugging showed that I can also fix the unresponsiveness while keeping the checkboxes, I just have to comment out another 2 lines of codes, which prevent the display of my table widget and another grid layout:

```
   

 self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.record_data_checkbox, 5, 0, 1, 4)
    # self.generalLayout.addLayout(self.recordDataLayout, 6, 0, 3, 4)
    
    # self.generalLayout.addWidget(mytable, 5, 4, 5, 8)
    self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.button_start, 9, 0, 1, 4)
```

These 2 workarounds leads me to guess that `PyQT` cannot handle the way I coded the `UI` elements and this causes the unresponsiveness. Weird, I thought my app is  just a very simple one.

**Full code** (edited, I removed the timer and sensor update codes mentioned in comments, and the issue is still there)

```
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGridLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QLabel, QSizePolicy, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow, QWidget, QCheckBox, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHeaderView, QLineEdit
from joblib import load
from time import sleep
import serial
import my_functions
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from functools import partial
import os
from threading import Thread

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.setWindowTitle('Smart E-Nose GUI')
        self.init_vars()
        self.generalLayout = QGridLayout()
        self._centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._centralWidget)
        self._centralWidget.setLayout(self.generalLayout)

        self.initialize_plot()
        self.init_classifier_pane()
        self.init_general_layout()
        # self.initialize_timer()

    def init_vars(self):
        self.BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        self.MODEL_PATH = os.path.join(self.BASE_DIR, 'models')


    def init_classifier_pane(self):
        self.classifierLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.classifierLayout.addWidget(QLabel('<h3>Classifier</h3>'), 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.classifierLayout.addWidget(QLabel('<h3>Prediction</h3>'), 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.classifierLayout.addWidget(QLabel('<h3>Ensemble result</h3>'), 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.classifiers = {}

        counter = 1
        for filename in os.listdir(self.MODEL_PATH):
            f = os.path.join(self.MODEL_PATH, filename)
            print(f)
            # checking if it is a file
            if os.path.isfile(f) and filename.endswith('.joblib'):
                dict ={
                "object": None,
                "checkbox": None,
                "label": None
                }
                clf_name = filename.replace('.joblib', '')
                self.classifiers[clf_name] = dict
                # dictionary
                self.classifiers[clf_name]['object'] = load(f)

                self.classifiers[clf_name]['checkbox'] = QCheckBox(str(clf_name))
                self.classifiers[clf_name]['checkbox'].setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
                self.classifiers[clf_name]['checkbox'].setStyleSheet("padding-left: 10px; border: 1px solid black;")
                self.classifierLayout.addWidget(self.classifiers[clf_name]['checkbox'], counter, 0, 1, 1)

                self.classifiers[clf_name]['label'] = QLabel('-')
                self.classifiers[clf_name]['label'].setStyleSheet("padding-left: 10px; border: 1px solid black;")
                # self.classifiers[clf_name]['label'].setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
                self.classifierLayout.addWidget(self.classifiers[clf_name]['label'], counter, 1, 1, 1)

 

                counter += 1
                
        self.myimage = QLabel('image')
        self.myimage.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black;")
        self.classifierLayout.addWidget(self.myimage, 1, 2, counter - 1, 1)
        self.generalLayout.addLayout(self.classifierLayout, 0, 4, 5, 8)
    
    def init_general_layout(self):
        """Create the buttons."""
        mytable = QTableWidget()
        mytable.setRowCount(4) 
        mytable.setColumnCount(3)
        arr = []
        data = {'col1':['1','2','3','4'],
        'col2':['1','2','1','3'],
        'col3':['1','1','2','1']}
        print(data)
        for n, key in enumerate(sorted(data.keys())):
            arr.append(key)
            print(key)
            for m, item in enumerate(data[key]):
                print(item)
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem(item)
                mytable.setItem(m, n, newitem)
        # mytable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(arr)
        # mytable.resizeColumnsToContents()
        # mytable.resizeRowsToContents()
        mytable.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        mytable.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
            QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.button_start = QPushButton('Start Session')
        self.button_start.setStyleSheet("background-color: #58FB00; ")
        # self.button_start.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        
        self.recordDataLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.record_data_checkbox = QCheckBox('Record session data')


        lbl = QLabel('Data Label')
        lbl.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black;")
        self.recordDataLayout.addWidget(lbl, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        lbl = QLabel('Data Description')
        lbl.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black;")
        self.recordDataLayout.addWidget(lbl, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        lbl = QLabel('Sampling frequency (Hz)')
        lbl.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black;")
        self.recordDataLayout.addWidget(lbl, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.data_label_txtbx = QLineEdit()
        self.data_description_txtbx = QLineEdit()
        self.recordDataLayout.addWidget(self.data_label_txtbx, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.recordDataLayout.addWidget(self.data_description_txtbx, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    
    
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.record_data_checkbox, 5, 0, 1, 4)
        self.generalLayout.addLayout(self.recordDataLayout, 6, 0, 3, 4)
        
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(mytable, 5, 4, 5, 8)
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.button_start, 9, 0, 1, 4)
        
        
        # action called by the push button


    def init_classifiers(self):
        from prepare_data_from_Excel import LE_classes
        self.LE_classes = LE_classes
        self.LABEL = 'banana'
        self.DETAILS = 'banana batch 3'
        self.record_data = 0
        

    def start_button_clicked(self):
        self.init_classifiers()
        self.init_serial_comms()
        self.timer.start()

    def init_serial_comms(self):
        # set up the serial line
        self.ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)
        sleep(2)
     


    def initialize_plot(self):
        self.canvas = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        # self.canvas.axes.plot([0,1,2,3,4], [10,1,20,3,40])
        # Create toolbar, passing canvas as first parament, parent (self, the MainWindow) as second.
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        # Create a placeholder widget to hold our toolbar and canvas.
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(widget, 0, 0, 5, 4)

        self.xdata = []
        self.ydata = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

        # We need to store a reference to the plotted line
        # somewhere, so we can apply the new data to it.
        self._plot_ref = {}
        # self.update_plot()

#=======================================================================
#  Model
#=======================================================================
class UI_model:
    pass
#=======================================================================
#  Controller
#=======================================================================
# Create a Controller class to connect the GUI and the model
class UI_Controller:
    """SmartENose's Controller."""
    def __init__(self, model, view):
        """Controller initializer."""
        self._model = model
        self._view = view
        # Connect signals and slots
        self._connectSignals()

    def _connectSignals(self):
        """Connect signals and slots."""
        self._view.button_start.clicked.connect(partial(self._view.start_button_clicked))
    


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = MainWindow()
    view.show()
    model = UI_model()
    # UI_Controller(model = model, view=view)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Simplified codes**
I simplified the codes to be easily reproducible as suggested.
You may run this gui on your side with no problem if you have matplotlib and PyQT5 installed. I noticed that it can be run without any lag as opposed to the full codes. In general, I simply removed the iteration of file from directory and the loading of the file by replacing the file names as hardcoded string, i.e., 'file1.joblib'.

```
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGridLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QLabel, QSizePolicy, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow, QWidget, QCheckBox, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHeaderView, QLineEdit
from functools import partial
import os

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.setWindowTitle('Smart E-Nose GUI')
        self.init_vars()
        self.generalLayout = QGridLayout()
        self._centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._centralWidget)
        self._centralWidget.setLayout(self.generalLayout)

        self.initialize_plot()
        self.init_classifier_pane()
        self.init_general_layout()
        # self.initialize_timer()

    def init_vars(self):
        self.BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        self.MODEL_PATH = os.path.join(self.BASE_DIR, 'models')


    def init_classifier_pane(self):
        self.classifierLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.classifierLayout.addWidget(QLabel('<h3>Classifier</h3>'), 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.classifierLayout.addWidget(QLabel('<h3>Prediction</h3>'), 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.classifierLayout.addWidget(QLabel('<h3>Ensemble result</h3>'), 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.classifiers = {}

        counter = 1
        for filename in ['file1.joblib', 'file2.joblib', 'file3.joblib', 'file4.joblib']:
        # for filename in os.listdir(self.MODEL_PATH):      
            # f = os.path.join(self.MODEL_PATH, filename)
            # checking if it is a file
            if filename.endswith('.joblib'):
                dict ={
                "object": None,
                "checkbox": None,
                "label": None
                }
                clf_name = filename.replace('.joblib', '')
                self.classifiers[clf_name] = dict
                # dictionary
                # self.classifiers[clf_name]['object'] = load(f)

                self.classifiers[clf_name]['checkbox'] = QCheckBox(clf_name)
                self.classifiers[clf_name]['checkbox'].setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
                self.classifiers[clf_name]['checkbox'].setStyleSheet("padding-left: 10px; border: 1px solid black;")
                self.classifierLayout.addWidget(self.classifiers[clf_name]['checkbox'], counter, 0, 1, 1)

                self.classifiers[clf_name]['label'] = QLabel('-')
                self.classifiers[clf_name]['label'].setStyleSheet("padding-left: 10px; border: 1px solid black;")
                # self.classifiers[clf_name]['label'].setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
                self.classifierLayout.addWidget(self.classifiers[clf_name]['label'], counter, 1, 1, 1)

 

                counter += 1
                
        self.myimage = QLabel('image')
        self.myimage.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black;")
        self.classifierLayout.addWidget(self.myimage, 1, 2, counter - 1, 1)
        self.generalLayout.addLayout(self.classifierLayout, 0, 4, 5, 8)
    
    def init_general_layout(self):
        """Create the buttons."""
        mytable = QTableWidget()
        mytable.setRowCount(4) 
        mytable.setColumnCount(3)
        arr = []
        data = {'col1':['1','2','3','4'],
        'col2':['1','2','1','3'],
        'col3':['1','1','2','1']}
        print(data)
        for n, key in enumerate(sorted(data.keys())):
            arr.append(key)
            print(key)
            for m, item in enumerate(data[key]):
                print(item)
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem(item)
                mytable.setItem(m, n, newitem)
        # mytable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(arr)
        # mytable.resizeColumnsToContents()
        # mytable.resizeRowsToContents()
        mytable.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        mytable.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
            QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.button_start = QPushButton('Start Session')
        self.button_start.setStyleSheet("background-color: #58FB00; ")
        # self.button_start.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        
        self.recordDataLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.record_data_checkbox = QCheckBox('Record session data')


        lbl = QLabel('Data Label')
        lbl.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black;")
        self.recordDataLayout.addWidget(lbl, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        lbl = QLabel('Data Description')
        lbl.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black;")
        self.recordDataLayout.addWidget(lbl, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        lbl = QLabel('Sampling frequency (Hz)')
        lbl.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black;")
        self.recordDataLayout.addWidget(lbl, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.data_label_txtbx = QLineEdit()
        self.data_description_txtbx = QLineEdit()
        self.recordDataLayout.addWidget(self.data_label_txtbx, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.recordDataLayout.addWidget(self.data_description_txtbx, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    
    
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.record_data_checkbox, 5, 0, 1, 4)
        self.generalLayout.addLayout(self.recordDataLayout, 6, 0, 3, 4)
        
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(mytable, 5, 4, 5, 8)
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.button_start, 9, 0, 1, 4)
        
        
        # action called by the push button


    def init_classifiers(self):
        from prepare_data_from_Excel import LE_classes
        self.LE_classes = LE_classes
        self.LABEL = 'banana'
        self.DETAILS = 'banana batch 3'
        self.record_data = 0
        

    def start_button_clicked(self):
        self.init_classifiers()
        self.init_serial_comms()
        self.timer.start()

    def init_serial_comms(self):
        # set up the serial line
        self.ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)
        sleep(2)
     


    def initialize_plot(self):
        self.canvas = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        # self.canvas.axes.plot([0,1,2,3,4], [10,1,20,3,40])
        # Create toolbar, passing canvas as first parament, parent (self, the MainWindow) as second.
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        # Create a placeholder widget to hold our toolbar and canvas.
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(widget, 0, 0, 5, 4)

        self.xdata = []
        self.ydata = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

        # We need to store a reference to the plotted line
        # somewhere, so we can apply the new data to it.
        self._plot_ref = {}
        # self.update_plot()

#=======================================================================
#  Model
#=======================================================================
class UI_model:
    pass
#=======================================================================
#  Controller
#=======================================================================
# Create a Controller class to connect the GUI and the model
class UI_Controller:
    """SmartENose's Controller."""
    def __init__(self, model, view):
        """Controller initializer."""
        self._model = model
        self._view = view
        # Connect signals and slots
        self._connectSignals()

    def _connectSignals(self):
        """Connect signals and slots."""
        self._view.button_start.clicked.connect(partial(self._view.start_button_clicked))
    


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = MainWindow()
    view.show()
    model = UI_model()
    # UI_Controller(model = model, view=view)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and provide a [mre], as almost 75% of your code is completely useless for this question.

Comment: By commenting out your `my_functions` module, *sensor readings* and `joblib` loading, I managed to show the MainWindow on the screen. I tried to create lots of `.joblib` files in order to load 20 or so checkbox widgets, and there was no lag at all. The application behaved normally as expected.

Comment: My guess is that you're freezing the GUI with this method: `update_sensor_reading`. By using `QTimer`, you're calling this method each second, which iterates over all checkboxes, and executes a very complex script which takes a lot of time to process. As that runs on the main thread, it freezes your application whenever it's called.

Comment: One way to fix that, is to use `QThreads`. There are lots of tutorials on the internet telling you how to use it.

Comment: the reason it is working on your side may be because the full code I posted earlier already commented out the 2 lines stated in workaround 2. Sorry for that, I just uncommented the 2 lines in the  full code section  by editing the post.

Comment: I commented out the timer codes and it is still laggy.

Comment: @user19499885 please make more efforts in making the code *actually* minimal and still reproducible. There are still a lot of unnecessary things (including more than half of the imports). Also use `@username`to reply when more than 2 users are in the conversation, otherwise they won't receive a notification.

Comment: @musicamante Hi, first of all, thank you for guiding me on posting  properly here on stack overflow :)

Comment: @musicamante I have edited my post that includes a simplified version of the gui (see 'Simplified code' section), hopefully you can run on your side with ease.
The simplified code can run without any lag.
I posted an answer.
I am just a beginner here at stack overflow, but thank you again, I will keep improving myself.

Comment: Remove `mytable.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)`, which is completely pointless since you're already setting the `Stretch` mode for all sections. And, please, for future reference, *do* make more efforts in creating a MRE that is **actually minimal**: your latest example is still full of code that is completely irrelevant for the question.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the issue disappears in the simplified version of code, without iterating through directory to load real file. I suspect os.listdir is interfering with PyQT operations.

Good news is, I also found the temporary workaround for the issue in my full code where I need to iterate my file system. I noticed that the following method of initializing checkbox will cause the issue in my full code:

```
filename = 'xxx.joblib' (filename loaded from directory)
clf_name = filename.replace('.joblib', '')
self.classifiers[clf_name]['checkbox'] = QCheckBox(clf_name)
```

```
Instead, I have to do this without modifying the filename string:
filename = 'xxx.joblib' (filename loaded from directory)
clf_name = filename
self.classifiers[clf_name]['checkbox'] = QCheckBox(clf_name)
```

I do not know why the .replace (or even .removesuffix method) will cause the issue in my **Full code**

Comment: If you tracked down the lines of the problem, start inspecting about what they do; for instance, print the original string, and then the replaced one. Look if the string already existed in the dictionary (which might be cause of the actual problem, and that's also a reason for which dictionaries should always be used with care for setting hierarchical references).

Comment: when clf_name = filename,
the printing of the variable and its type is as follow:
clf_name > Random Forest.joblib
type(clf_name) > <class 'str'>

when clf_name = filename.replace('.joblib', ''),
the printing of the variable and its type is as follow:
clf_name > Random Forest
type(clf_name)  > <class 'str'>

There is no essential difference.
This solution is really trivial.